# How to find out that mqtt-paho publish failed due to ACL?

Tags: python, mqtt, acl, paho

I'm using paho.mqtt Python library. I have an ACL list set up on my MQTT broker. However, I can't see any difference between publishing to a topic I have rights to and publishing to a topic I don't have rights to.

I set up `on_connect` and `on_publish` callbacks in following ways:

```
def on_connect(args, client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        msginfo = client.publish(args.topic, args.string, qos=2, retain=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f"Publish rc {msginfo.rc}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to connect, return code {rc}\n")

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print(f"On publish: userdata:{userdata}, mid:{mid}")
```

I get the same output:

```
Connected to MQTT Broker!
Publish rc 0
On publish: userdata:None, mid:1
```

in both cases. Is there a way to get the information "Publish failed because of authorization/ACL"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you don't (at MQTT v3.x)

Slightly longer answer:

MQTT v5 introduced flags in the response packets for Messages published with QOS 1 or 2 (QOS 0 are not acknowledged so no way to signal not authorised)

https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901124

If your broker supports MQTT v5 then you can try passing the relevant options (protocol=MQTTv5)to the paho client at connect time to see if you get a different answer. I've not tried so can't be sure if it will throw an error that can be caught by the `on_error` callback or if it will just not call the `on_published` callback.

Comment: It seems that what I want isn't possible at this moment. Connect, disconnect, subscribe and unsubscribe callbacks have their v5 versions (e.g. `_OnConnect` and `_OnConnectV5` in `client.pyi`) which can take `ReasonCodes` and `Properties`.

Sadly, `_OnPublish` doesn't have a v5 version.